# Defining Terminal Segments

Tags: logic, definition

In logic, the definition of initial segments is the following:

> Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be strings. Then $\tau$ is an initial segment of $\sigma$ if $lh(\tau) \leq lh(\sigma)$ and for some $i < lh(\tau)$, $\tau_{i} = \sigma _{i}$. (where $lh$ is length of the string)

My professor did not define terminal segments (and he did not hint what a terminal segment might be) and I cannot find the definition anywhere (or I find definitions in different lingo so I am unsure if it is the right definition). If you know the definition of terminal segments in logic, I really appreciate you help me!

Comment: Frankly speking, I do not see any interest in defining it... Having said that, is what remains of $\sigma$ when we have removed its initial segment $\tau$. Thus, counting the position in $\sigma$, it will be made of $<\sigma_{lh(\tau)+1} \sigma_{lh(\tau)+2} \ldots \sigma_{lh(\sigma)}>$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Final segment" is basically the dual of "initial segment" - a final segment of a string $\sigma$ is a string that $\sigma$ "ends with," in the same way that an initial segment of a string $\sigma$ is a string that $\sigma$ "begins with."

Formally, $\tau$ is a final segment of $\sigma$ if there is some string $\hat{\tau}$ such that $\hat{\tau}{}^\smallfrown\tau=\sigma$  (where "$^\smallfrown$" denotes concatenation of strings).

For example, taking $\sigma=\langle 1,2,3,4,5\rangle$:

- The initial segments of $\sigma$ are:

  - $\langle 1,2,3,4,5\rangle$
  - $\langle 1,2,3,4\rangle$
  - $\langle 1,2,3\rangle$
  - $\langle 1,2\rangle$
  - $\langle 1\rangle$
  - $\langle\rangle$ (this is sometimes denoted "$\Lambda$").
- The final segments of $\sigma$ are:

  - $\langle 1,2,3,4,5\rangle$
  - $\langle 2,3,4,5\rangle$
  - $\langle 3,4,5\rangle$
  - $\langle 4,5\rangle$
  - $\langle 5\rangle$
  - $\langle\rangle$